# Detectar ID de item en Buscador Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Hola estoy realizando un buscador de productos en una base de datos MySQL usando PHP y Ajax para la busqueda en tiempo real; He encontrado una librería de Twitter llamada [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) que me facilita el trabajo.

**Lo que busco realizar**:
La descripción de los productos en mi tabla `products` son guardados en una variable `$array` para luego mostrarlos en pantalla, lo que quiero es poder detectar el `id` del producto que he presionado para redireccionar a otra pantalla por ejemplo, `productDetail.php?id={ID-DETECTED}`, ahora mismo al presionar el item desplegado solo me hace un auto completado del input.

**Lo que he intentado**:
El buscador con Ajax también me sirve como un "Autocomplete" entonces he creado un botón extra llamado buscar que me envía como parámetro la descripción del producto y en base al resultado de esa búsqueda me muestre el ID de ese producto, pero no se como hacer la redirección
usando por ejemplo `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="productDetails?getId=">Buscar</a>` debido a que con este botón le estoy enviando la descripción a mi query, agradecería que me sacaran de este enredo que tengo.

Archivo **Index.php**

```
    <html>

<head>
      <title>Ajax Search</title>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
      </script>
      <script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
                name: 'typeahead',
                remote: 'Buscador.php?key=%QUERY',
                limit: 10
            });
        });
      </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bs-example {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            position: relative;
            margin: 50px;
        }
        
        .typeahead,
        .tt-query,
        .tt-hint {
            border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
            border-radius: 8px;
            font-size: 24px;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            outline: medium none;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            width: 396px;
        }
        
        .typeahead {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        
        .typeahead:focus {
            border: 2px solid #0097CF;
        }
        
        .tt-query {
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
        }
        
        .tt-hint {
            color: #999999;
        }
        
        .tt-dropdown-menu {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            margin-top: 12px;
            padding: 8px 0;
            width: 422px;
        }
        
        .tt-suggestion {
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 24px;
            padding: 3px 20px;
        }
        
        .tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
            background-color: #0097CF;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        
        .tt-suggestion p {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class=".col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="bs-example">
                    <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search a product...">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="productDetails?getId=">Buscar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

El archivo que genera la consulta **Buscador.php**

```
<?php
    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","MYDATABASENAME");

    //recibo la descripcion del input
    $prodDescription= trim($_POST['typeahead']);

    $query2=mysqli_query($con, "select id,pro_description from TABLENAME where pro_description 
    = $prodDescription");
    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2))
    {
     $proID = $row2['id'];
    }
    
    $query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from TABLENAME where pro_description LIKE '% 
    {$key}%'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      $array[] = $row['pro_description'];
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Resultado actual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería cualquier comentario que me ayude a solucionar esta duda.

Comment: Con _typeahead_ puedes obtener diferentes propiedades, aunque solo muestres el nombre. Seguramente [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/440818/54039) puede servirte de guía para lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Gracias @Triby, estoy investigando un poco mas sobre la librería, cuando logre resolver publicare una respuesta.